# Getting Null values when using strtok [C]

Tags: c, strtok

I am working on a project which involves using `strtok` and for some reason I am getting null values instead of the actual values (which should be "Two" and "Three"). Here is my code:

```
int main(){
    int h,z;

    char text[100] = "One Two Three";

    for(h = 0; h < 4; h ++){

        char *first = strtok(text, " ");
        printf("%s\n",first);

        for(z = 0;  z < 3; z++){
            char *second = strtok(NULL,  " ");
            printf("%s\n",second);


        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
One
Two
Three
One
(null)
(null)
One
(null)
(null)
One
(null)
(null)
```

What can I do in order to get the right value `Two` and `Three` instead of null?

Comment: `z < 3` -> `z < 2`
?

Comment: @StephanLechner I have done that but still I am getting the same output - null

Comment: `strtok()` *modifies the string* by inserting string terminators into it in place of the delimiters it discovers.  Thus if you truly want to tokenize the same input multiple times, as you are trying to do by running the whole thing in your loop over `h`, then you must avoid tokenzing the original string.  Make copies and tokenize those.

Comment: @Lucas You are getting null because the code does not make sense. You may mark my answer as the best.:)

Comment: To fix it , move `char text[100] = "One Two Three";` to inside the `h` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your code actually re-tokenizes the string `text` 4 times, as you have nested loops. Note also that `z < 3` is one off and should be `z < 2`:

```
int main(){
    int h,z;

    char text[100] = "One Two Three";

    for(h = 0; h < 4; h ++){

        char *first = strtok(text, " ");
        printf("%s\n",first);

        for(z = 0;  z < 2; z++){
            char *second = strtok(NULL,  " ");
            printf("%s\n",second);


        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But `strtok` introduces `'\0'`-characters each time a token is found. Hence, after the first run of the `for(h...)`-loop, `text` will be `"One"`, and for any subsequent loops only one token can be found; tokens #2 and #3 do not exist in `"One"`.

To re-tokenize (for whatever reason), you'll have to re-initialize `text`:

```
int main(){
    int h,z;

    char text[100];

    for(h = 0; h < 4; h ++){

        strcpy(text,"One Two Three");

        char *first = strtok(text, " ");
        printf("%s\n",first);

        for(z = 0;  z < 2; z++){
            char *second = strtok(NULL,  " ");
            printf("%s\n",second);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this makes sense. Is there any way that I can go around this - avoiding '\0' from being appended

Comment: @Lucas: not with `strtok`; This function always introduces a `'\0'` when a token is found. So either copy the original value into `text` again and again, or choose another algorithm (e.g. based on `strchr` and `strncpy`), or `sscanf`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You could tokenize the string , save it in a double pointer and print it as many times you want!